# tailwind background images are visible on localhost but not visible after hosting it on github

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

```
  backgroundImage: {
    heroBg: "url(./src/images/Randelo-hero.jpg)",
    testimonialsBg: "url(./src/images/testimonial-bg.jpg)",
    dailyDeloBg: "url(./src/images/daily-delo-bg.jpg)",
    homeMadeBg: "url(./src/images/home-made-img.jpg)",
    contactBg: "url(./src/images/contact-bg.jpg)",
  }
```

this is what i have on my tailwind.config.js
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vscode\Randelo\src\images\Randelo-hero.jpg this is the path to my images
this is the tailwind classname bg-heroBg
this is my first using tailwind and i'm coming across this error
./src/images/daily-delo-bg.jpg referenced in C:/Users/HP/Desktop/vscode/Randelo/src/App.css didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime
this is the error i am getting

i have tried inline styling

Comment: its good to put your images in public folder

and the url be like that: "url("images/Randelo-hero.jpg")

Comment: I have tried that too, still didn't work. I even tried inline css all giving me the same error